# Webkit inputs with autofocus don't apply CSS :focus styles

Tags: css, input, webkit, focus, autofocus

If I set the `autofocus` attribute on an `<input>` element...

```
<input type="search" id="search" autofocus />
```

And then style its focused state...

```
#search:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #428bca;
}
```

When my page loads, the `autofocus` attribute will place the cursor in the search field automatically as it should – but the `box-shadow` I've specified won't appear unless I still manually focus the field, either by clicking on it or starting to type.

Is this a WebKit bug or the expected behavior?

Comment: On Opera 15 and it works fine. I mean, the shadow appears on page load itself.

Comment: My search input is hidden by default – would that affect whether the :focus styles apply? It still autofocuses even though it's hidden initially...

Answer (score 0):

Try `-webkit-box-shadow:` and see if that fixes it

Comment: I'm using PrefixFree, so `box-shadow` works. It's not the property that's the problem, it's that it only applies on manual focus.